Extracting data from irregular nested structure
I have a data frame which can be represented by this sample:
structure(list(Created = structure(c(1723114609.889, 1723120797.26, 
1723129821.436), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), `Root Cause` = list(structure(list(type = "text", text = "Sample Text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    NULL, NULL)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

How can I mutate the Root Cause column so that entries which contain NULL are replaced with "tbc" and entries which contain data are replaced with the data in the text field, i.e. the Root Cause for the first row will read "Sample Text"?
I can achieve it with a for loop with
for(i in 1:nrow(issues_df)) {
  if(ncol(as.data.frame(issues_df$`Root Cause`[i])) == 0) {
    issues_df$`Root Cause`[i] <- "TBC"
  } else {
    issues_df$`Root Cause`[i] <- as.data.frame(as.data.frame(issues_df$`Root Cause`[i])$content)$text
  }
}

But I feel like doing it within a mutate would be a more efficient and idiomatic approach.

You can also tidyr::hoist() a value from a nested column and replace missing values with tidyr::replace_na() :
library(tidyr)

df_
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   Created             `Root Cause`
#>   <dttm>              <list>      
#> 1 2024-08-08 10:56:49 <df [1 × 2]>
#> 2 2024-08-08 12:39:57 <NULL>      
#> 3 2024-08-08 15:10:21 <NULL>

df_ |> 
  hoist(`Root Cause`, `Root Cause_` = "text") |> 
  replace_na(replace = list(`Root Cause_` = "TBC"))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Created             `Root Cause_` `Root Cause`
#>   <dttm>              <chr>         <list>      
#> 1 2024-08-08 10:56:49 Sample Text   <df [1 × 1]>
#> 2 2024-08-08 12:39:57 TBC           <NULL>      
#> 3 2024-08-08 15:10:21 TBC           <NULL>

Created on 2024-08-09 with reprex v2.1.1

Running this on the latest sample of my data frame returns the error:
<error/vctrs_error_cast>
Error in vec_assign():
! Can't convert replace$Root Cause_  to match type of data$Root Cause_ .
Backtrace:
▆

├─tidyr::replace_na(...)
└─tidyr:::replace_na.data.frame(...)
└─vctrs::vec_assign(x = col, i = missing, value = value, x_arg = col_arg, value_arg = value_arg)


From the error I'd guess the text column type of some nested tibbles is logical and not character , though without a sample that reproduces this error it's just a guess.

If element in Root Cause is a dataframe extract the text column from it or else return "TBC".
With dplyr you may do this with rowwise :
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(`Root Cause` = if(is.data.frame(`Root Cause`)) `Root Cause`$text else "TBC")

#  Created             `Root Cause`
#  <dttm>              <chr>       
#1 2024-08-08 10:56:49 Sample Text 
#2 2024-08-08 12:39:57 TBC         
#3 2024-08-08 15:10:21 TBC   

and similarly in base R :
df$`Root Cause` <- sapply(df$`Root Cause`, \(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) x$text else "TBC")


Using is.null:
mutate(issues_df, `Root Cause`=ifelse(is.null(`Root Cause`), "TBC", `Root Cause`$text))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Rowwise: 
  Created             `Root Cause`
  <dttm>              <chr>       
1 2024-08-08 10:56:49 Sample Text 
2 2024-08-08 12:39:57 TBC         
3 2024-08-08 15:10:21 TBC

